# Game Engine Script Not Running

Tags: scripting, game-engine

My script won't execute when the game initiates.

It's just a simple "print('Hello')". It works when I click "run script" but not automatically when the game initiates. I have tried 3 different versions of Blender and still no luck.

When I used to use Blender, about 2 years ago, I remember it working fine, but for some reason it has stopped working. Is there anything I can do? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to BSE! Do you have a python controller with the script selected in your game? And does it run on startup? You might want to upload a .blend because we have very little information right now

Comment: Have you (re)tried your script with the version of Blender it was written for at the origin ?

Comment: @palkonimo I don't think I do but I don't recall needing it, maybe I'm wrong. Here is the .blend file: http://www.filedropper.com/untitled_143

Comment: @lemon I have tried that.

Comment: ok... you have tried that, but does it still work ? (nothing is explicitly said about that). Can you indicate the Blender version used at the origin ?

Comment: @lemon It doesn't work on anything anymore, even the origin version, which is 2.61.

Comment: You MUST have this link into your favs https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77a_release/

Down the pages are the game engine commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your python script is not running because you only created it, you did not tell it to run.  To do this, first open up the *Logic Editor*.[image: Step 1]

Then, create an *Always Sensor*, and a *Python Controller*.  Set the script to be the name of your script (In this case, Text).  Now, click *Level* on the *Always Sensor*, to make it run once. 
[image: Step 2]

Finally, connect the two blocks, and you're good to go!
[image: Step 3]

Here is the result in the command line:
[image: Done]

Answer (score 1):

Your script ins't executed anywhere. If you want it to be executed at the start of your game you'll need to have an always sensor connected to a python controller having the script in it. This can be in any object. [image: the setup]

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel stupid lol I remember doing this now from before.